# Azure function trigger with IoT-Hub "EntityPath"

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub, azure-triggers

I am currently having troubles with connecting my function trigger to an IoT-Hub, overnight it broke somehow.
Function version 4.
Node.js version 14 LTS.

First I got an error saying I have to use web.jobs version 4.3.0, I changed the host.json to include this

[image: host.json]

Then it has started giving me a runtime error which I don't know how to fix, the error:

[image: "[Error in the azure portal(EntityPath)][2]]

I defined connection string in the portal which has the format

```
"Endpoint=sb//{iothub-ns-"somename"-"somenumber".servicebus.windows.net/}; SharedAccessKeyName={NameOfAccessKey};SharedAccessKey={TheKey};EntityPath={Name};
```

Lastly I tried removing the EntityPath which removed the error but then nothing came to the function anymore

Edit:
I got it fixed by changing function version to 3 and reverting the original Host.json to be "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)".

I have no idea how the runtime version got changed, even when I made new functions they would also get this error. It is probably just something I have done within my workspace that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

while defining the connection string give the entity path as even hub compatible name

```
Endpoint=sb://<Event hub-compatible endpoint>.servicebus.windows.net/;EntityPath=<Event Hub compatible name>;SharedAccessKeyName=<keyName>;SharedAccessKey=<key>"
```

Comment: I should probably have made anew comment instead of making an edit to my post, but I did figure out a fix.

I got it fixed by changing function version to 3 and reverting the original Host.json to be "version": "[2.*, 3.0.0)".

I have no idea how the runtime version got changed, even when I made new functions they would also get this error. It is probably just something I have done within my workspace that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's an open bug, reported here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3034